# Python watchdog to monitoring github repos changes

Tags: python, github, watchdog

I need an help to create a python watchdog system to monitor a GitHub repo.
The idea is: every time something new is pushed on a repo (master), I'd like to update my repo on a server with the new commits/push.

Any idea how can do this?

Answer (score 4):

**OK! I've found 2 solutions for this**

## **1.** If you own the repo that you want to watch

- In you're repo page, Go to settings
- click webhooks, new webhook (top right)
- give it your ip/endpoint and setup everything to your liking
- use any server (such as in @pigeonhands answer) to get notified

## 2. Not your Repo

- take the url you want i.e https://github.com/fire17/gd-xo/
- add ***/commits/master.atom*** to the end such as:

  https://github.com/fire17/gd-xo/commits/master.atom
- Use any library you want to get that page's content, like:

> ```
> import requests; 
>
> response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json").text
> ```

- filter out the keys you want, for example the  element

> ```
> >>> response.split("<updated>")[1].split("</updated>")[0]
> '2021-08-06T19:01:53Z'
> ```

- make a loop that checks this every so often and if this string has changed, then you can initiate a clone/pull request or do whatever you like :)

I'm so happy to finally achieve this capability
Hope this helped!

Comment: When recreating the problem to display the response, @user3196006, I received an error message that the "list index is out-of-range" for the update. Which approaches should I take to extract the element when I changed the index to `response.split("<updated>")[1].split("</updated>")[0]`, the output displays a series of HTML code which is different to the expected output showed in your answer. Would you like to verify the statements on filtering out the keys?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the [github 'push' webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#push).
This means instead of continually polling the repo for changes, you can setup a web service where github can tell you when a push has occurred.

A very basic example with flask might look like this

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import hmac

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/myhook", methods=['POST'])
def github_push_webhook():
    signature = request.headers.get("X-Hub-Signature")
    digest = hmac.new(GITHUB_SECRET.encode(), request.data, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()

    if not hmac.compare_digest(signature, "sha1=" + digest):
        abort(400, "Bad Request")

    webhook_data = request.get_json()
    changed_repository = webhook_data.get('repository')
    # clone the repoisitory...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you own the repo the best way is via webhooks as @pigeonhands suggested, otherwise either a scraper or rss feed combined with telegram/discord/slack webhooks

reference: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22956